# change lockscreen settings on a particular time

Tags: android

The concept of my personal app is:

I can set (like the alarm app) everyday a timespan for example: every monday from 13:00 until 16:00 hour my lockscreen is enabled.

This is because I don't like the lockscreen after my workhours but I like it when I'm on my work.

Now I did some research and you need to do this with broadcastreceivers and the AlarmManager so the app doesn't run the whole day (correct me when I'm wrong).

What I don't find in the developer guide is how to change the lockscreen settings. Some people on the internet say you need a rooted phone, but I really don't like the rooted part. Is there any way to solve this problem without a rooted phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html